# How can I create a MySql function in C#?

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm trying to create a mysql function in C#. The reason I'm doing this is because I want to loop through multiple mysql databases and create the function in each one.

The problem is that the MySqlCommand does not like the DELIMITER syntax required to create the function. The script below executes fine in MySql clients, but does not work in this context:

```
DELIMITER //
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS cleandate //
CREATE FUNCTION cleandate(mydate DATE) 
RETURNS DATE
READS SQL DATA

BEGIN
RETURN  (CASE WHEN mydate <= '1900-01-01' THEN '1900-01-01' WHEN mydate = '0000-00-00' THEN '1900-01-01' 
        WHEN DATE_FORMAT(mydate, '%Y') = '0000' THEN '1900-01-01'
        WHEN DATE_FORMAT(mydate, '%m') = '00' THEN '1900-01-01'
        WHEN DATE_FORMAT(mydate, '%d') = '00' THEN '1900-01-01'
        ELSE mydate 
        END);
END//
```

The c# code trying to implement this(assuming connstrings is a List of strings):

```
foreach(var connstring in connstrings)
{
    // Create connection to database
    MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection dbConn = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection(connstring);

    MySqlCommand cmd = dbConn.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = @"[same script here]";

    try
    {
        dbConn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (Exception erro)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(erro.ToString());                    
    }
}
```

I get the "syntax error near DELIMITER //" when I run this though. Any ideas how I can achieve this?

Comment: Normally you don't create SQL functions in code. Define them by hand and USE them in your code

Comment: I've tried this years ago with an ODBC connection (in VBA) with a little success; but I don't recall the details. One thing that stands out with your example though is that you are trying to execute multiple statements in one call; most database APIs don't allow that without at least setting some additional options on the connection (if at all). _(Edit: It was ADODB over ODBC, and didn't need a `DELIMITER` override.)_

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The MySQL Connector offers a MySqlScript class that can be used in place of MySqlCommand when dealing with executing multiple statements and setting delimiters.

Adapted to your example:

```
foreach(var connstring in connstrings)
{
    MySqlConnection dbConn = new MySqlConnection(connstring);

    try
    {
        dbConn.Open();

        MySqlScript script = new MySqlScript(dbConn);

        script.Query = @"[same script here]";
        script.Delimiter = @"//";
        script.Execute();
    }
    catch (Exception error)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(error.ToString());                    
    }
}
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-mysqlscript.html

Comment: Can't believe I didn't know about the MySqlScript class. This worked for me! Thanks!

Comment: I did also figure out you can actually execute it without a delimiter...to me it wasn't obvious since I read that you had to use a delimiter when creating a function. Oh well, now we know you can do both if needed.